# Developing iOS Meteor app on DigitalOcean

Tags: linux, xcode, meteor, digital-ocean

I need to develop an app compatible with iOS using Meteor. I'm going to put my project into a digitalocean droplet.
How can I run iOS-supported app from linux-based DigitalOcean droplet if iOS support requires Xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would first build the meteor app and deploy it to Digital Ocean. I would recommend MUP for the deployment process. It's super straight forward and easy. Sacha Greif has a great video on setting up the droplet.

https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WLGdXtZMmiI

Then you will build the meteor app for iOS

```
meteor add-platform ios
```

Follow this MDG wiki page for more info on building for iOS... https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap-integration

Basically, if you want to run in a simulator, you can use the following command:

```
meteor run ios --mobile-server http://<your deployed server address>
```

If you want to build for iOS distribution, you can use the following command:

```
meteor build <bundle path> --server http://<your deployed server address>
```

Comment: I'm using windows as my local system and, if I understand correctly, mup does not support it. Would building a meteor app directly on digitalocean server be a valid option in this case?

Comment: Oh ya, probably. I did not realize you were on windows. Ya, I would use a Vagrant box to develop locally and then mup it up to your server. You could also deploy to Modulus with Windows I believe.

Answer (score 0):

With Meteor & Cordova your app is built in 3 pieces: Server, Client and Cordova.

The server is what you would put on DigitalOcean typically. The apps outputted by the `meteor build` would be the XCode project - *not the ipa binary*, the Android APK (if you build for android too) and the node server app.

You wouldn't be able to build the binary on DigitalOcean for iOS without Xcode but you can run the nodejs server app which would be your app's backend. Instead of the binary the raw Xcode project files are created in the output directory of `meteor build`. So you would need Xcode to build the binary on OS X which you could then upload to the app store.

So you could run the backend on the DigitalOcean droplet without the need of Xcode. It's just building the binary once off for the app store that would need an OS X machine.

The nodejs app would also serve up the client files if you loaded up the DigitalOcean droplet's URL in your browser.